# Churchill's quote: "This is just the sort of nonsense up with which I will not put."

Tags: history, language, quotes, winston-churchill

Did Winston Churchill say, [as some on the 'net claim](http://www.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/churchill.html), in response to being told he should not end a sentence with a preposition, something like "This is just the sort of nonsense up with which I will not put."

Comment: I heard EBWhite had the record for dangling prepositions. A mother was going to read a book about Australia to her son, who didn't want it and said "What did you bring that book about Down Under up for?"

Comment: There've been quotes attributed to Churchill that were said by other people, so I wouldn't be surprised if this one is bogus.

Comment: @Mike technically "Down Under" is a noun phrase in this context, but still impressive.

Comment: @Mike, @DJ, I have heard a different version: "Daddy, what did you bring that book that I didn't want to be read to out of up for." e.g. http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/001084.html

Comment: @Oddthinking: Good one. That gets rid of the "noun phrase" objection.

Comment: The OP's question ends with a verb, "put". I think he meant "...with which I shall not put *up* "

Comment: @MikeDunlavey The version I heard was something like "Mommy, what did you bring that book that I didn't want to be read to from out of about Down Under up for?"

Comment: @KeithThompson: Precious!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Probably not.  Here is evidence of a [1948 attribution to Churchill in Parliament](http://hansard.millbanksystems.com/commons/1948/mar/18/government-english#S5CV0448P0_19480318_HOC_565), though it had previously [appeared in 1942 as an anonymous statement](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/001715.html) and the [Churchill Centre and Museum](http://www.winstonchurchill.org/learn/speeches/quotations/famous-quotations-and-stories) concludes it was

> an invented phrase put in Churchill’s mouth.

Answer (score 1):

The source is actually a humourous story in the Strand Magazine, May, 1942. See here (The Quote Investigator):
http://quoteinvestigator.com/2012/07/04/churchill-preposition/
Churchill never said it.

Comment: Can you flesh up this answer? What is the evidence presented?